# DateTimeField not saving the Time and Date DJANGO2.1

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have tried countless times different approach to save and `TIME and DATE` using `DateTimeField`  but DJANGO2.1 keep throwing a template error `enter a valid date/time`

## models.py

```
class Party(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

## forms.py

```
class PartyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField()
    date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(format=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'], 
                                        attrs={'class':'myDateClass', 'type':'datetime-local'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Party
        fields = ['name', 'date']
```

## views.py

```
from .models import Party
from .forms import PartyForm

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PartyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            
    else:
        form = PartyForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'core/index.html', context)
```

## index.html

```
<div class="container mt-5 ml-5">
      <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
```

## settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

USE_L10N = False
```

Also, when i try to use `input_formats` below:

```
date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'], 
                                        attrs={'class':'myDateClass', 'type':'datetime-local'}))
```

The terminal throw the error below:

```
File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_fun4/date_and_time/date_time/core/forms.py", line 30, in PartyForm
    attrs={'class':'myDateClass', 'type':'datetime-local'}))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_formats'
```

## Extra info

When I try to save the DATE only. the configuration below work.
I changed `'type'` value to `'date'`

```
date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format=('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'),attrs={'class':'myDateClass', 'type':'date'}))
```

but when I try to save both DATE and TIME where `'type':'datetime-local'` django template throw the error ENTER A VALID DATE/TIME

Can anybody help me figure out how to save the TIME and DATE.

## (Time is the most important data i need right now but if i can save both TIME and DATE it would be great)

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: please could you share the view too ? (and just to know, does it work with `USE_L10N = True` ?)

Comment: @PRMoureu Yes, I have updated the views.py and template above.

Comment: @PRMoureu no, updating ```USE_L10N = True``` does not change anything. What I notice though, If i just want to use the DATE and change ```,attrs={'class':'myDateClass', 'type':'date'}))``` where ```'type' value is changed to 'date'```it will work and save ```ONLY THE DATE```. when i try to use ```datetime-local``` the template ask me to enter a valid date and is no longer saving.

Comment: can you give an example of input dates ?

Comment: this works. ```date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format=('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'),attrs={'class':'myDateClass', 'type':'date'}))``` because i changed the value of ```type``` to ```date``` which means only the date is needed. when i try to use ```datetime-local``` again, error in template.

Comment: @PRMoureu just in case you bump into the same annoying issue, it was easier and less time consuming using this package ```https://django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html```

Answer (score 2):

That `format` is a string argument, try with:

```
date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', attrs={'class':'myDateClass', 'type':'datetime-local'}))
```

or provide no format at all and Django will try to apply some of [these](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats).

Comment: the template return the error: "Enter a valid date/time.".

Comment: do you believe my TIME_ZONE configuration in settings.py and mentioned above as anything to do with this not working property?

Comment: What happens when you set type as `'type':'datetime'`?

Comment: the widget disappear from the form therefore the form because just a blank form to manually enter only TYPED information. Im not sure but i feel like the missing part is in template im currently reading online maybe i should use ```type=datetime-local``` there as well then add a button for submit.

Comment: Where's that "myDateClass" defined and have you tried without that custom class, just the default `date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.DateTimeInput())`?

Comment: i just copied "myDateClass" from another example, not sure what is does. the default is the same result. the widget disappear as your previous question. I need to consider another approach because ```datetimelocal``` widget does not show on certain browser like safari etc...

Comment: That class is iirc CSS class used to render that widget, if you don't have it in your imported css files then you should omit it.

Comment: just in case you bump into the same annoying issue, it was easier and less time consuming using this package ```https://django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html```